# Signing 20-byte message with 256-bit RSA key working with openssl.exe but not in code

Tags: cryptography, openssl, rsa

I have a 256-bit private key that I want to use to sign a SHA-1 digest (20 bytes). Using openssl directly it seems to work

> echo doesntmatter | openssl dgst -sha1 -binary | openssl rsautl -sign -inkey 256bit_private_key.pem | openssl enc -base64

gives me a Base64 output as expected.

But doing it with the OpenSSL fails with "error:04075070:rsa routines:RSA_sign:digest too big for rsa key". As you can see below, I'm passing the 20-byte (SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH=20) SHA-1 digest as input to RSA_sign. Even with padding it shouldn't be more than the maximum of 32 bytes that I can encrypt with a 256 bit modulus key?!

```
unsigned char digest[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
SHA1(message, messageSize, digest);

unsigned int privateKeySize = RSA_size(privateKey); // 256 bits = 32 bytes
unsigned char* signature = new unsigned char[privateKeySize];
unsigned int signatureSize;

int res = RSA_sign(NID_sha1, digest, SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH, signature, &signatureSize, privateKey);

if(res == 0)
{
    int err = ERR_get_error(); // 67588208
    char *s = ERR_error_string(err, 0); // error:04075070:lib(4):func(117):reason(112)

    delete [] signature;

    [...]
}
```

What am I doing wrong in the code?

Comment: Is this c? Please specify programming language!

Comment: The code is C++, but that shouldn't matter

Comment: a 256-bit RSA key is pretty intensely insecure... I hope this is just for a school project or something not for something "real"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess I found the solution. `openssl rsautl -sign` uses `RSA_private_encrypt` instead of `RSA_sign` (what I would have expected). `RSA_sign` creates a longer structure than the 20-bytes message I provided, so it fails with the given error.

Answer (score 3):

check out this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10443732/1904979). `rsautl` is depreciated in favor of `pkeyutl`

Essentially, RSA signing should use RSA-PSS signature padding scheme to be secure, and the RSA-PSS will be strictly larger than the digest, because of the necessity to communicate a salt. additionally, `RSA_sign` does a digest as a part of the signing scheme, so your code is going to do a digest of a digest.   you want to instead either pass the message in directly, or use `RSA_private_encrypt` combined with a suitable `RSA_padding_add_x` call.

and as I said in my comment, a 256-bit key is sufficiently secure for a symmetric algorithm, but it will be trivial to crack for an RSA private key (on the order of [4 minutes on a couple of year old machine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/28678)).  Using a bare minimum of a 1024 bit key (and probably a 2048 or 4096 bit key) will give you a [security level](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Security_Level) roughly equivalent to a 128 bit symmetric algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! My use case is a bit different and luckily not really security-related, else I'd change to a larger key and `RSA_sign` immediately.

Answer (score 3):

Re Peter Elliott: not quite.

The PKCS1v1_5 standard sequence in [RFC8017 section 8.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-8.2.1) (and 9.2, similar in rfc4347 and rfc3447) is hash, encode in ASN.1, pad ('type 1') and modexp d. (PSS omits the ASN.1 step and uses different padding.)

OpenSSL (low-level) `RSA_sign` does the last three (with v1.5 padding) but not the first -- i.e. it *encodes* the hash but it doesn't *do* the hash; even-lower `RSA_private_encrypt` does the last two.
The higher-level envelope module (original `EVP_Sign{Init,Update,Final}*`, enhanced `EVP_DigestSign*`) does all four.
It's the ASN.1 encode that made the value too large for a 256-bit key -- which as stated is breakable anyway.

`rsautl` does only the last two steps not the encode, so it runs but gives a nonstandard result.
`pkeyutl` for RSA does the same by default but can be told to do the encode.

Also, PSS has a better security proof, but as far as I've heard there's no actual attack on v1.5 and it's still widely used.
If you have the choice of PSS (both/all parties support it) choose it, but don't feel worried about using v1.5.