# Multiple OpenSSL RSA signing methods produce different results

Tags: openssl, rsa, sign

Trying to wrap my head around signing and use/test various options.

I can sign using this command:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -sign private_key.pem -binary -out sig_file data_file
```

But the documentation seems to say that I can also use this method

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -binary data_file > hash_file
openssl rsautl -sign -inkey private_key.pem -keyform PEM -in hash_file > sig_file2
```

But the signatures are different when I'd expect them to be identical. Either I missed something in the options or something else is wrong in my assumptions.

The real question from this issue: Is there a way to sign using command line options given that I already have the hash value and produce a signature that is identical to the first command above.

To add more to this, I can reproduce the first command easily in code and it matches the first command above meaning that I can sign with the hash value calculated first.

```
mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();
EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx, EVP_sha256(), NULL);
EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, data, len);
EVP_DigestFinal_ex(mdctx, hash, &s);
EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(mdctx);

kfile = fopen64(key_file, "r");
key = PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(kfile, NULL, NULL, NULL);
fclose(kfile);

*sig = malloc(RSA_size(key));
RSA_sign(NID_sha256, hash, hlen, *sig, siglen, key);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dupe: [Difference between openSSL rsautl and dgst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951559/difference-between-openssl-rsautl-and-dgst)
Closely related:
[Why are the RSA-SHA256 signatures I generate with OpenSSL and Java different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419201/why-are-the-rsa-sha256-signatures-i-generate-with-openssl-and-java-different?rq=1)
[Different signatures when using C routines and openssl dgst, rsautl commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380856/openssl-signature-difference-when-using-c-routines-and-openssl-dgst-rsautl-comm)
[Signing 20-byte message with 256-bit RSA key working with openssl.exe but not in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092298/signing-20-byte-message-with-256-bit-rsa-key-working-with-openssl-exe-but-not-in)
Crossdupe: https://superuser.com/questions/943972/what-is-the-difference-between-openssl-pkeyutl-sign-and-openssl-rsautl-sign

**TLDR**: `dgst -sign` for RSA does the full RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5: hash the data, encode the hash in ASN.1, pad the result, and modexp d. `rsautl -sign` does only the last two and `dgst` by itself only the first, thus **skipping the encode** producing a different and nonstandard signature. `dgst` (or your own hash) then **`pkeyutl -sign`** with an RSA key **and `-pkeyopt digest:name_of_digest` (important!)** also works and answers your real question.