# Is there any equivalent command to compute the sha256withRSA signature by openssl?

Tags: openssl, rsa, sha256

I have a file to be signed by following command:

```
$ openssl sha256 -sign privatekey.pem myfile.txt > right.result
```

Is there any equivalent command to get the same result? I have tried the following method (calculate the sha256 digest firstly, then sign the digest). But it can not work:

```
$ openssl sha256 -binary myfile.txt > my.digest
$ openssl rsautl -sign -inkey privatekey.pem -in my.digest > wrong.result
```

The content of *"wrong.result"* is always different from *"right.result"*. Could someone tell me the reason? Thank you very much!

Comment: Dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38767660/multiple-openssl-rsa-signing-methods-produce-different-results/38768455 and others linked there

Answer (score -1):

Using `openssl sha256 -sign ...` makes openssl compute the PKCS#1 "SHA256withRSA" algorithm, fully specified by RFC-8017.

**This does not simply means doing a SHA-256 digest and sign it with RSA**, as you did in the second part of your example.

Here is why:

According to this RFC, the signature must have the same length than the RSA modulus. Your RSA modulus is 512 bits long (default value using `openssl genrsa`) or more, so the computed signature MUST have a length of 512 bits (or more). Even if the hash function (HMAC-SHA256) returns values of 256 bits length.

So, to compute a signature with 512 bits, from a 256 bits only HMAC-SHA256 digest, RFC-8017 requires you to use the I2OSP Integer-to-Octet-String primitive, that takes 2 arguments: your 256 bits hash, and the integer 512 (the length of your RSA modulus). I2OSP will output a 512 bits length octet string. finally, this is this octets string that will be encrypted with your RSA private key.

**But you have not computed this intermediate Integer-to-Octet-String value.This is why your signatures do not match.**