# OpenSSL C++ RSA sign is different from command line sign

Tags: c++, openssl, rsa, digital-signature, sign

I'm trying to sign a text in C++ and then verify it in the command line. I'm using OpenSSL libraries. This is my command line for key generation:

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem 1024
```

Now I have my private key. Then this is how I do to sign in command line:

```
echo "hola" | openssl rsautl -pkcs -sign -inkey key.pem > sign.txt
```

At this point all works like it seems to be, now I have a sign in sign.txt.
Now I'm trying to do the same in C... This is my code:

```
RSA * rsaPrivKey;


RSA * createRSAWithFilename (const char * filename, int publicKey)
{
   FILE * fp = fopen (filename, "rb");

   if (fp == NULL)
   {
      printf ("Unable to open file %s \n", filename);
      return NULL;
   }
   RSA *rsa = RSA_new ();

   if (publicKey)
      rsa = PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY (fp, &rsa, NULL, NULL);
   else
      rsa = PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey (fp, &rsa, NULL, NULL);

   return rsa;
}


void initRSA (void)
{
   rsaPrivKey = createRSAWithFilename ("key.pem", 0);

   unsigned char text[] = {"hola"};
   unsigned char encrypted[4098] = {};
   unsigned int outlen;

   unsigned char hash[20];
   if (!SHA1 (text, sizeof(text), hash)){
      printf ("SHA1 failed\n");
      exit (0);
   }
   if (!RSA_sign (NID_sha1, hash, 20, encrypted, &outlen, rsaPrivKey)){
      printf ("RSA_sign failed\n");
      exit (0);
   }

   printf ("Result:\n");
   for (int a = 0; a < outlen; a++)
      printf ("%c", encrypted[a]);

   exit (1);
}
```

When I call initRSA() it prints the generated signature.. but.. is not the same as in generated in command line.

Because not sure about if the sizeof is taking the real length of "text" I tried with length = 4 (hola have 4 chars) and 5 (perhaps computing \0) and the results are not the expected.

My knowledge in cryptography is very limited.. don't know where is the problem.

Comment: Please include the library you are using in your code (i.e `#include <lib>` part)

Comment: Without knowing your OS, in all implementations of echo I've ever come across echo "hola" is not equivalent to "hola", but rather "hola\n".

Comment: agreed with Arne. Try echo -n "hola" ;)

Comment: Also see [EVP Signing and Verifying](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Signing_and_Verifying) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently it's because you're using the wrong command line.  You want this command line, which computes a digest of your input and signs it using the private key:

```
echo -n "hola" | openssl dgst -sha1 -binary -sign key.pem >sign.txt
```

Using pkeyutl does some other extra stuff as described here: [Different signatures when using C routines and openssl dgst, rsautl commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380856/openssl-signature-difference-when-using-c-routines-and-openssl-dgst-rsautl-comm/10443732#10443732)

So if you use the command line I provided (use `echo -n` to avoid adding a newline) and change your code to `sizeof(text)-1` to skip the null terminator, you should get the same output.

Comment: Hi kcraigie, Thanks... thats the problem and nor works fine :)... Thanks a lot, I'm very frustrated.