# Sign DKIM emails manually with openssl.exe

Tags: batch-file, openssl, dkim, windows-scripting

We are deploying a console application based batch files to send emails. We take the content from the standard input and then pass it to Bmail and MgSMTP server.

Now we want to add a DKIM signature to the email. Since the app is written in batch, the only way to sign hashes is using `openssl.exe`.

I already have the bodyhash and the headerhash hashed with sha1 and encoded in base64.

The question is: How can I dkim sign emails?

Answer (score 1):

Well, after some research I found very useful this:
[OpenSSL C++ RSA sign is different from command line sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33814916/openssl-c-rsa-sign-is-different-from-command-line-sign)

```
echo "%headerhash%" | openssl rsautl -sign -inkey key.pem -out tempfile.pem
```