# OpenSSL Digitally Sign Digest Only

Tags: openssl, digital-signature

I have a signing server where you can upload a file and it will respond with the digital signature.

It is using `openssl dgst -sha256 -sign` which works fine.

However, we've had to start signing large files (>1 GB) and the uploads take forever. I had the idea that we could compute the sha256 digest locally and pass just that to the signing server which would speed things up considerably. However, this seemingly simple task seems crazy hard with openssl. Is there a reason for this?

I found one possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16264508/2516916) but it's very complicated compared to the current `dgst` one-liner and involves generating an ASN1 config file.

Is this really the only way of generating digital signatures with openssl without needing the file present?

Comment: IMHO you need either or both of; more CPU, faster STORAGE. I know of no better solution, given your constraints.

Comment: Huh? I don't get it...

Comment: Apologies; I read it too fast. Your problem was *uploads*, not processing the file itself. Sorry. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apparently want an *RSA* signature, specifically OpenSSL's default of RSASSA-PKCS1v1_5, although your question didn't say so and OpenSSL supports several other signature algorithms. And you ignored comment linking #9951559
to [Different signatures when using C routines and openssl dgst, rsautl commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380856/different-signatures-when-using-c-routines-and-openssl-dgst-rsautl-commands/10443732#10443732) as well as dupe [Multiple OpenSSL RSA signing methods produce different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38767660/multiple-openssl-rsa-signing-methods-produce-different-results) and more linked there.

`rsautl` does not do the ASN.1 DigestInfo encoding at step 2 of [rfc8017 et pred 9.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-9.2), but since 1.0.0 in 2010 `pkeyutl` does *if* you specify the digest algorithm:

```
openssl pkeyutl -sign -inkey privkey.pem -pkeyopt digest:sha256
# note input is binary; if you transport to the server as hex, use
# xxd -r -p or the printf $(echo $x | sed 's/../\\x&/g') hack or similar
# output is also binary by default, like rsautl which you seem to handle
```

Or the same section of PKCS1 (rfc8017 et pred) has constant prefix values for all standard hash-with-RSA schemes, which is still simpler than working out DER.

Comment: This is great, I really appreciate this response. I've updated my other answer using the information from yours. Forgive my inexperience with OpenSSL; because it is such a broad swiss-army-knife-esque utility, I was overwhelmed with information and having trouble filtering the relevant bits (and in the process skipped over some relevant comments, as you noted).

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Using @dave_thompson_085's answer, I created the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: $0 <sha256 digest>

# Example usage: ./sign_256sha.sh 5d525e3513b493798a7ac353401ef040ea6de92809485292201b8f27731e6379

# Input to openssl pkeyutl is binary, not ASCII hex,... need to convert using xxd
echo $1 | xxd -r -p | openssl pkeyutl -sign -inkey privkey.pem -pkeyopt digest:sha256
```

which is equivalent to:

`openssl dgst -sha256 -sign privkey.pem <file>`

as long as the sha256 digest of `<file>` is passed to the first.